# Access Denied while installing pytorch/tensorflow on windows10

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, anaconda, conda

I tried to install Tensorflow in the anaconda prompt using the command: `conda install tensorflow`
I received the following error message:

```
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::scipy-1.1.0-py36h672f292_0'.
PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')
Attempting to roll back.
Rolling back transaction: done
PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')
```

Similarly when I tried to install pytorch via `conda install -c pytorch pytorch`:

```
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::conda-4.5.4-py36_0'.
PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')
Attempting to roll back.
Rolling back transaction: done
PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')
```

I checked and ran those commands with administrator privileges.
How to solve this problem and install tensorflow in conda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Read the docs for uninstalling Anaconda https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall
- Do a conda install anaconda-clean
- Then do anaconda-clean --yes
- Then download Anaconda for Windows Installer and run thru the steps. https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#windows
- Then re-install tensorflow using the command you tried to use.
- If this does not work, you might have python concurrency (between built-in python and manually installed python versions).

Comment: It didn't work, but i found a soultion. I created a new virtual environment and i installed there Tensorflow and an older version of numpy. but thank you for your help